# Issue with Page in OAF

Tags: oracle, jdeveloper, oracle-ebs

Hello Guys,
               Being new to OAF, i have one folder in patch under myprojects as demo.oracle.apps.server as well as webui. Now , i am trying to just run the first page created under webui directory and i have setup the database connection and assigned the application as sysadmin as i have system administrator responsibility. But while running the page which literally does not have a code in Jdeveloper , throws below error:

oracle.apps.fnd.framework.OAException: Application: FND, Message Name: FND-INVALID APPLICATION. Tokens: APPL = webui;

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved by changing the application name.